# Get a specific word using awk

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, mysql, text-processing

I am coding a script to check mysql databases using bash script, I would like to check if the status of a table is not 'OK', will return the table name and do some more actions:

check.log

```
table1                 OK
table2                 Some error here
table3                 OK
table4                 OK
table5                 Another error
table6                 OK
table7                 Broken
table8                 A very long error which take a 2 lines
of multiple errors
```

check.sh

```
# check and repair tables
mysqlcheck -u $hostUser -p$hostPasswd --all-databases --check --auto-repair >> check.log

# grep tables status, should return OK
cat check.log | grep 'OK' | awk '{print $2}'| while read status; do

# if any table does not contain OK
if [ "$status" != "OK" ]
then
##### HERE WHERE I am stuck
#### It loops and return all the table

# grep to get the table name
cat check.log | grep 'OK' | awk '{print $1}'| while read table; do
echo $tblName' is BROKEN'
done
else
echo $tblName' is FINE'
fi

done

// here I need to mail the tables that have problems in one single mail
```

Looking for an output like:

```
tableName: error
tableName: error

table2: Some error here
table5: Another error
and so on
```

These lines will be an output into a log file (result.txt)

Thanks for your support

Comment: Do you have a specific reason to use `awk`?

Comment: Well if there is a better method, why not

Answer (score 6):

You don't need to read file line-by-line using bash. Awk does that already. For instance, you can print broken entries using this code

```
awk '$2!="OK"{print $0}'  check.log
```

You can also just print the table name and use that command to create an array, then act upon those:

```
array=( $(awk '$2!="OK"{printf "%s ",$1 }'  check.log) )
```

Note the space next to `%s`, that's important.

You mentioned also, that error can be multiline, just like for table8. We probably want to avoid messing with that. So we may add a check also for field 1 to contain a word table.

```
$> array=( $(awk '$1~/table/ && $2!="OK"{printf "%s ",$1 }'  check.log) )      
$> echo ${array[@]}                                                            
table2 table5 table7 table8
$> echo ${array[0]}                                                            
table2
```

Comment: Oh yeah, awesome, how can I print the content of the array?

Comment: Either echo or printf will do. See my edit

Comment: Tables can have different names, I am looking to get a result like the above mentioned in my edited question

Comment: @AbuRayane that's it ? You just want lines like `tableX Error#25` ?

Comment: In that case , `awk '$2!="OK"{print $0}'  check.log`, my first code is what you want.

Comment: I found that with this behaviour the array has only one parameter, and I could not do a loop, for example for field in array do...

Comment: I think something is missing , there's not enough clarity in your question.  What bothers me a lot is the table 8 , it breaks a pattern. Why  the error in that table is multiline ?

Comment: mysqlcheck will return some errors in a very long line (so to prevent that, I am saying it CAN be multi line) to not have any error in the code

Answer (score 3):

Since `awk`'s default behaviour is to print the full line when a True condition happens, you can say something as simple as this:

```
awk '$NF != "OK"' file
```

Which returns the following for your given input:

```
table2                 Some error here
table5                 Another error
table7                 Broken
table8                 A very long error which take a 2 lines
of multiple errors
```

#### Explanation

- `NF` stands for number of fields, so `$NF` stands for field number `NF`. That is, the last field on every line.
- Saying `$NF != "OK"` we are checking if the last field on the line is "`OK`" or not. If it is not, the condition is true and the line gets printed automatically.

Comment: It is a good toot, I am looking to print the result per rows, as I edited in my question above, see the part "Looking for an output like:"

Comment: @AbuRayane you should edit your question to show what exact output you want. Currently it is unclear.

Comment: The solutions that you give and Serg as well gave me, are correct, it is only a matter of a display, I need to display the result line by line, i.e: table2: error then a new line table3: error another new line table5: error and so on

Comment: @AbuRayane so instead of the full error you just want to display the string "error"?

Comment: No, the full error, but line by line display as mentioned above

Comment: @AbuRayane this is a bit tiring. Edit your original question indicating what exact output you want. You are currently saying either `tableName: error` and `table2: Some error here`. This is very unclear.